# What happens if I terminate jUnit tests

Tags: java, junit

I have a weird question. If I get somehow stuck in my tests, I have to terminate them. But still I need to destroy a background process. Meaning I need some method that is called on the jUnit termination to override. Afterclass method or Finalize aren't it. Is there something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, when you terminate a JVM there's not much you can do to react. Depending on how you stop it, [shutdown hooks](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)) may or may not run, but that's pretty much your only chance.